Service Workers and Change of CDN
I'm currently working to switch over a web application over from one CDN to another. Currently the application has a service worker in place and I'm hitting issues where the service worker is not registering changes upon go-live in the new CDN (the application is meant to reload when changes are recognized - and previously did so consistently). The files are hosted as filename.hash.js and should be different across the experiences but so far the application itself has not turned over upon switching of CDNs. Has anyone ever had experience with this issue?
